# Kernel panics with "Cannot open root device" error, where do I append the "root=" option?

Tags: 11.10, kernel

whenever I try to boot with linux kernel 3.0.0.13 (the one installed by the upgrades) I get a Kernel Panic error:

> VFS: Cannot open root device "sda1" or unknown block (0,0) 
>   Please append a correct "root=" boot option;

Luckily enough if I boot using the previous version I don't have any issue.
How can I solve this? Where should I append the correct `root= option`? If I don't get this Kernel to work, how can I remove it as the default and stick to the older one?

Comment: Same problem here. The main difference I observe is that up to 3.0.0.12, the grub conf tries to identify the hard disk using its UUID, 3.0.0.13 now uses /dev/sda6 .. weird ...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't provided much information with logs and such to proceed with but I am guessing most probably this error you're facing is because the kernel is confused by a IDE/SATA drive. Doing a quick Google search led me to [link 1](http://forums.funtoo.org/viewtopic.php?id=273), [link 2](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/unable-to-boot-on-vmware-workstation-6-5-kernel-panic-824851/), [link 3](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/kdump-vfs-error.html)

*Following is the excerpt from a [link referred to](http://swift.siphos.be/linux_sea/ch07.html) by [one of the links above](http://forums.funtoo.org/viewtopic.php?id=273):*

> Most likely one of the most occurring issue (but once you solved it,
>   you most likely are never going to see it again):
>
> ```
> Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> VFS: Cannot open root device "sda3" or unknown-block(8,3)
> Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
>   sda driver: sd
>     sda1 sda2
> ```
>
> The digits `0,0` or `8,3` can be different in your case - it refers to
>   the device that the kernel tries to access (and which fails).
>   Generally speaking one can say that, if the first digit is 0, then the
>   kernel is unable to identify the hardware. If it is another digit
>   (like 8), it is unable to identify the file system (but is able to
>   access the hardware).
>
> The problem here is that the kernel that you are booting cannot
>   translate the `root=/dev/...` parameter you gave it (inside the boot
>   loader configuration) into a real, accessible file system. Several
>   reasons can result in such a failure:
>
> - the kernel configuration is missing drivers for your HDD controller    (cases 1, 4, 5)
> - the kernel configuration is missing drivers for the bus used by your    HDD controller
> - the kernel configuration is missing drivers for the file system you    are using
> - the device is misidentified in your root= parameter (cases 2, 3)
>
> Resolving the issue is easy if you know what the reason is. You most
>   likely don't, so here's a quick check-up.
>
> Open the kernel configuration wizard (the **make menuconfig** part) so
>   that you can update the kernel configuration accordingly.
>
> - Check if you have built in (and not as a module) support for the bus    / protocol that your harddisk controller uses.
> - Most likely this is PCI support, SATA support (which is beneath SCSI    device support), ...
> - Check if you have built in (and not as a module) support for the HDD    controller you use.
>        One of the most frequent cases: you selected support for your    harddisk controller protocol (IDE, SATA, SCSI, ...) but forgot to
>     select the HDD controller driver itself (like Intel PIIX). Try
>     running the following lscpi command, and paste its output on
>     http://kmuto.jp/debian/hcl/. The site will show you which kernel 
>     drivers you need to select for your system. Within the menuconfig,
>     you can type "/" to open the search function, and type in the driver
>     name to find out where it resides.
>        `# lspci -n`
> - Check if you have built in (and not as a module) support for the file    system(s) you use.
> - Say your root file system uses btrfs (which I definitely don't    recommend) but you didn't select it, or selected it to be built as a
>     module, then you'll get the error you see. Make sure the file system
>     support is built in the kernel.
> - Check if the kernel parameter for `root=` is pointing to the correct    partition.
>
>   This isn't as stupid as it sounds. When you are booted with one
>     kernel, it might list your disks as being /dev/sda whereas your
>     (configured) kernel is expecting it to be /dev/hda. This is not
>     because kernels are inconsistent with each other, but because of the
>     drivers used: older drivers use the hda syntax, newer sda.
>
>   Try switching hda with sda (and hdb with sdb, and ...).
>
>   Also, recent kernels give an overview of the partitions they found
>     on the device told. If it does, it might help you identify if you
>     misselected a partition (in the example given at the beginning of this
>     section, only two partitions are found whereas the kernel was
>     instructed to boot the third). If it doesn't, it is most likely
>     because the kernel doesn't know the device to begin with (so it can't
>     attempt to display partitions).
> - Check if the kernel that is being boot by the boot loader is the    correct kernel.
>        I have seen people who, after building a first kernel (which doesn't    boot), forget that they have to mount `/boot` before the
>     overwrite the    kernel with a new one. As a result, they copy the
>     kernel to the root    file system (`/`) whereas the boot loader still
>     expects the kernel    image to be on the `/boot` partition.

Comment: Hi, it passed a lot of time, but thanks.

I had a faulty CD-Rom, removing that everything worked fine!

Comment: Link 1, Link 4 and Link 5 are all dead now.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible this error could be related to the initrd image being too large.

A solution to this can be accomplished by changing the compression method and removing debug symbols from object files:

```
# Strip unneeded symbols of object files
$ cd /lib/modules/5.4.5-rt3  # or your new kernel
$ sudo find . -name *.ko -exec strip --strip-unneeded {} +

# Change the compression format
$ sudo vi /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf
# Modify COMPRESS=lz4 to COMPRESS=xz (line 53)

COMPRESS=xz
```

reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59678390

Answer (score 0):

After reading this answer which explains what is going on, try using the [Boot-Reapir CD][1][1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Worked great at repairing the "the device is misidentified in your root= parameter (cases 2, 3)".