# VFS: Cannot open root device [UUID] or unknown-block(0,0) / Kernel panic not syncinc VFS

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel, boot-failure, boot-partition

I am running Ubuntu 11.10 x86-64 in Virtual Box. While shutting down the last time the system ran normally, it seemed to have hung up, so I just killed the system. When I wanted to boot it again, nothing happened. If I go to recovery mode in GRUB I get following information:

```
VFS: Cannot open root device "UUID=99532d26-eb6b-43bf-8520-916a85d6a69d" in unknown-block(0,0)
Please append a correct "root=" boot option; here are the available partitions:
0b00         1048575 sr0  driver: sr
Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)
Pid: 1, comm:swapper Not tainted 3.0.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu
```

As I read in several other boards it seems that GRUB can't find '/'. So I booted from the (virtual) Live-CD and did the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt #according to `sudo fdisk -l` sda1 is my booting partition
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
sudo chroot /mnt
cp -r /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pango /usr/lib
update-initramfs -u -k 3.0.0-12-generic
update-grub2 #does not seem to work: Cannot find list of partitions!  (Try mounting /sys.)
```

Then I rebooted, chose the non-recover entry and nothing happened again. I did this like 3 times and it was the same always.

Hopefully somebody can help me. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to my own question:
Somehow uname gave me a wrong name (3.0.0-12-generic), but according to GRUB it's 3.0.0-19-generic. Executing `update-initramfs -u -k 3.0.0-19-generic` and rebooting made it work!

Answer (score 0):

Also read here: [Kernel Panics][1]

After reading the answers on the above post which explains what is going on, try using the [Boot-Reapir CD][1][1]: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Worked great at repairing the "the device is misidentified in your root= parameter (cases 2, 3)".

this answer[1]: [Kernel panics with "Cannot open root device" error, where do I append the "root=" option?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/71332/kernel-panics-with-cannot-open-root-device-error-where-do-i-append-the-root)